# upgrading from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS and stalled halfway through

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

I was doing a distribution upgrade through the update manager, after doing all the updates on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.  After getting the new packages, the installing of the upgrades made it half way and stopped.

This is the last entry in the terminal - 
DKMS:  install completed.

I have searched high and low and the best I could find in a forum for a similar situation was to enter the following commands in the terminal, which I did, with no results....
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove

I would like to know how to safely close down my laptop (Latitude D830/dual boot with Windows XP) so that I can do a fresh install of 16.04LTS (which is what I have been aiming for all along) from a download disc instead.  At this point it seams it would have been simpler to do a fresh install instead of these two upgrades.

Any assistance would be very appreciated from this newbie.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I pressed the off button and have installed a clean install of 16.04LTS...Unfortunately restart or shutdown on this clean install does not work...